# Save input to .csv on submit - Click submit nothing happens, but not errors either

Tags: r, csv, shiny, save, action

Have a small dashboard.
When the submit button is clicked there is no error, but there's also nothing written to the file.

The code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googlesheets4)
library(markdown)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(pander)

# Load local test data

dbrp_data2 <- read.csv(file = 'location of locally stored .csv file')

# Define the fields we want to save from the form

# Dashboard page

ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    # Begin dashboard header
    dashboardHeader(title = "DBRP"),
    
    # Begin dashboard sidebar
    dashboardSidebar(
        
        # Begin sidebar menu
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Artifact Entry", tabName = "artifactentry")
            # End sidebar menu
        )
        # End Dashboard sidebar
    ),
    
    # Begin dashboard body
    dashboardBody(
        
        # Begin tab items by tab name
        tabItems(
            
            # Begin first tab item
            tabItem(tabName = "artifactentry", h2("Artifact Entry"),
                    
                    # Begin first fluid row - artifact entry for submit and reset buttons
                    fluidRow(
                        
                        # Begin first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                        box(h3("Submit or Reset Data"), width = 7,
                            
                            # Begin first column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            column(3, h4("Submit Data"),
                                   # Submit action button
                                   actionButton("submit_artifact_entry", label = "Submit")
                                   
                                   # End first column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            ),
                            
                            # Begin second column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            column(3, h4("Reset Entries"),
                                   # Reset action button
                                   actionButton("reset_artifact_entry", label = "Reset")
                                   
                                   # End second column of first box of first fluid row - artifact entry
                            )
                            
                            
                            # End first box of first tab item - artifact entry
                        )
                        
                        # End first fluid row - artifact entry for submit and reset buttons
                    ),
                    
                    # Begin second fluid row - widgets to test area
                    fluidRow(
                        
                        # Begin box of second fluidRow - widgets to test area
                        box(h3("Widgets to Test"),
                            
                            # Begin first column of second fluidRow - widgets to test
                            column(4, h4("Widgets"),
                                   
                                   # Checkbox widget to test
                                   checkboxGroupInput("dbir", selected = NULL,
                                                      h4("Select Rating"),
                                                      c(
                                                          "Low" = "Low",
                                                          "Medium" = "Medium",
                                                          "High" = "High",
                                                          "Critical" = "Critical"
                                                      )
                                                      # End checkbox widget to test
                                   )
                                   
                                   
                                   # End box of second fluidRow - widgets to test area
                            )
                            
                            # End box second fluidRow - widgets to test
                        )
                        
                        
                        
                        # End second fluidRow - widgets to test area
                    )
                    
                    
                    # End first tab item
            )
            

            
            # End tab items by tab name
        )

        # End dashboard body
    )
 
    
    # End dashboard page
)

# Begin server functions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Rest button for artifact entry page
    observeEvent(input$reset_artifact_entry, {
        
        # Reset data breach rating check box
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "dbir", choices = c(
            "Low" = "Low",
            "Medium" = "Medium",
            "High" = "High",
            "Critical" = "Critical"), selected = NULL)
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit_artifact_entry, {
        
        submit <- data.frame(dbir = input$dbir)
        
        
        # append write of data on submit
        write.table(submit, "dbrp_test_data2.csv",
                    append = TRUE,
                    col.names = FALSE
                    
        )
        
    })

    
    # End server functions
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How do I get the value from the checkboxGroupInput into a file where the data appends every time i click submit?

I've gone to a couple of references and i'm now more confused than educated...sigh...

https://psyteachr.github.io/shiny-tutorials/index.html

https://psyteachr.github.io/shiny-tutorials/data-input.html#02_try_the_demo

https://github.com/ConalMonaghan/Shiny-Survey-and-Feedback-Site

https://www.learnbyexample.org/read-and-write-csv-files-in-r/

https://medium.com/@joyplumeri/using-r-shiny-to-create-web-surveys-display-instant-feedback-and-store-data-on-google-drive-68f46eea0f8b

Cheers ~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your data frame 'submit' has to be first a reactive value or a placeholder for several values.

```
ui:
your part from above

server:
    submit <- reactiveValues()
    submit$some_variable_name<- data.frame(dbir = input$dbir)

    write.table(submit$some_variable_name, "dbrp_test_data2.csv",
                    append = TRUE,
                    col.names = FALSE                  
        )
```

Comment: Ok - i'll try that real quick...should be hard to put the changes in...

Comment: Ok - so that worked - thanks!  I also had to add the exact file path in the write.table part of the code

Comment: now i have to figure out how to do this with a bunch of inputs on a single submit -

Comment: Then I would be happy if you would flag my answer as correct and gave it a thumbs up! You are welcome!

Comment: ok - i think i did that correctly...sorry i'm new to the stackover system.

Comment: also - i solved for placement in csv last night - app is now working as intended - thanks again.